# How to set cookie to the WebBrowser control only

Tags: javascript, cookies, browser, c#-2.0, webbrowser-control

I have a webbrowser control with flash video player inside. I want to set a cookie to the webbrowser control so I can play forbidden videos (that need this cookie). I don't want to set the cookie globally and affect IE's cookies. I tried with `webBrowser.Document.Cookie`, but nothing happened. Still forbidden. What to do?

Comment: can you just change the user agent of your webbrowser app to identify your browsers as something other than IE? Then you can differentiate the browsers at the server side.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the Navigate function and [add aditional headers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161356.aspx)

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.com", "", NULL, "Cookie :" + yourCookie + Environment.NewLine);
```